# pandas import issue with pyscripter

Tags: pandas, import, python-3.6, pyscripter

I have pyscripter version 3.2.2.0 x86 running python 3.6.3
When I want to import pandas in a py module(i.e. import pandas as pd), 
I end up with an exception : invalid syntax

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 424, in run_nodebug
  File "<module1>", line 13, in <module>
  File "D:\Users\Jean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "D:\Users\Jean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytz\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pytz.lazy import LazyDict, LazyList, LazySet
  File "D:\Users\Jean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytz\lazy.py", line 3, in <module>
    from UserDict import DictMixin
  File "D:/Users/Jean\Desktop/Kodi Python Development/PythonPourDebutants/App/Lib\UserDict.py", line 134
    raise TypeError, "pop expected at most 2 arguments, got "\
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but when I import in command line, everything is ok !
why is it so ?

thanks for your answers !

Comment: I found that if I delete from python path the particular paths I have added

D:/Users/Jean\Desktop/Kodi Python Development/PythonPourDebutants/App/Lib

it is ok now !

Comment: It seem that the UserDict module is no more needed with my python 3.6

Note: This module is available for backward compatibility only. If you are writing code that does not need to work with versions of Python earlier than Python 2.2, please consider subclassing directly from the built-in dict type.